# backbone : Collection and View rendering

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am really confused on this one and need help. (unrelated : "up for about 36 hours now to finish somthing and this last part is just making me go crazy")

## My Code

```
 <body>
<div id="mycontainer" style="margin: 20px; ">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="Myelement_template">
    <% _.each( results, function( item, i ){ %>
            <div id="Myelement" style="width: 200px; height:325px; padding: 10px; background-color: #2980b9;">
                <div id="image" style="width: 190px; height: 200px; margin: auto; background-color: #f1c40f;">
                    <img src="<%= item.get('category').url %>" style="max-width: 90%;margin-top: 10px;">
                </div>
                <div id="type" style="float:left;width: 90px; height: 25px; margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;background-color: #f1c40f;">
                    <%= item.get("category").type %>
                </div>
                <div id="name" style="float:left;width: 90px; height: 25px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;background-color: #f1c40f;">
                    <%= item.get("category").name %>
                </div>
            </div>                    
        <% }); %>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

CategoryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        url: '',
        type: '',
        name: ''
    }
});

MyListModal = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'myrestapi',
    defaults: {
        category: CategoryModel
    }
});

MyElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // bind 'this' in 'render'
        this.model = new MyListModal();
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.model.fetch(this.render);
     },
    el: $("#mycontainer"),
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.model.get("category"));
    }
});

 var myModelView = new MyElementView();
});
 </script>
```

## Question

My rest api will return many BaseModel objects. All of them need to be rendered. How do I do that?

1. console.log(this.model.get("category")); - code reaches here. not printing. debugging shows that rest api call was made and cata has been returned
2. How do I render all returned elements?

Sample Data returned by rest API

```
[
{
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "mytype1",
        "url": "myurl1"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 153
    },
    "status": 1
},
{
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name2",
        "type": "type2",
        "url": "url2"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 153
    },
    "status": 1
},
]
```

Comment: I m adding complete code. can you please help a little bit

Comment: How is that your data has 2 models with same id ? it seems v unlikely in backbone.Please confirm this.Additionally i would really suggest changing your MyListModal into a Backbone collection which would make more sense in the context.